# Any good sites or suggestion for jquery overlay dialog?

Tags: jquery, dialog, overlay

Hi i am new to jquery and i wanted to create a jquery overlay dialog in which i have some input fields like textboxes and radiobutton and ok and cancel button. i need to display a table on clicking ok button displaying all input fields in a webform. I have the basic dialog knowledge bt am confused how to implement this. Any sites or suggestion with similar tutorial will be a good learning for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[jQuery UI dialog demo: modal form.](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/modal-form.html)

Answer (score 0):

Jquery UI has what you need, easily styled as well and lots of examples:

http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/

Answer (score 0):

http://jqueryui.com/

http://fancybox.net/

http://www.shadowbox-js.com/index.html

http://colorpowered.com/colorbox/

If you have'nt started using jquery, give it a try. It is awesome. It will make your job easy.

http://www.jquery.com